# Multiple Extends in PHP

Tags: php, oop, extends

I've heard that you can't use extend twice.

I have two classes:

Base32 and SecureRandom

Which I need for TOTP.

How can I use both of these for it?

Comment: I might also be doing this wrong should I be doing a public function setKey() and passing the output of $secRand->bytes(10); ?

Comment: You could instantiate the classes inside the class you need them in.

Comment: You still can chain the classes:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9818728/277619

Answer (score 5):

Use [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) or [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) (include an instance of one of the classes as a member variable of the class).

Interfaces allow you to define prototypes for the methods in a class. A class then `implements` that interface and must define a method for each prototype in the interface. You can only inherit directly from one class (`extends`) but you can `implements` an arbitrary number of interfaces.

If you find that interfaces don't fit your task well, just use composition.

Comment: Composition is definitely the way to go in this circumstance. Just because you want a class to inherit functionality of another object doesn't mean it is a good fit for inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [PHP5.4 Traits](http://php.net/trait#language.oop5.traits) they kind of solving problem of multiple extends.

Combine them with interfaces to get instanceof functionality.

For example:

```
interface ClientAwareInterface {
    public function setClient($client);
}

trait ClientAwareTrait {
    protected $client;

    public function setClient($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}

class Shop implements ClientAwareInterface extends SomeClass {
    use ClientAwareTrait; // use our trait to implement interface methods
    use OtherTrait;
}

$shop = new Shop();
if($shop instanceof ClientAwareInterface) {
    $shop->setClient('test');
    var_dump($shop); 
}
```

Result would be:

```
object(Shop)[1]
  protected 'client' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't allow for multiple inheritance. You'll need to extend one of them and have the other as a private variable, or something like that.